# How to provide Space between Y-2 Axis Labels and Title at Y-2 axis in Flotr2 Multi-Axis Chart

Tags: javascript, css, flotr2

I'm Using Flotr2 for Multi-Axis Chart creation..

Here is the Flotr2 Multi-Axis Chart Image:
[image]

In this Multi-Axis Chart at Right side  Axis Labels and TITLE are overlapping..

I need How to provide some space between   Axis Labels and TITLE for easy reading.

I'm adding the reference of this Multi-Axis Flotr2 Chart Url: http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/#!advanced-titles

Can anyone help me pls..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug, as can be seen here:
https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/Flotr2/issues/151

A good workaround for me is to put in the page html an image with the axis title in the right corner of the graph,.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the labelMargin in the grid object.

```
  grid : {
    verticalLines : false,
    backgroundColor : 'white',
    labelMargin: 20
  },
```

Seems to help a bit, but it effects all the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, live with the bug for now.
Add spaces to the tick labels (the numbers) would do the trick making room for the axis label.

```
function addSpace(v,axis) {
 return Flotr.defaultTickFormatter(v,axis)+"   ";
}

...

y2axis: title:"Leistung (W)", tickFormatter:addSpace,
```

Three spaces (0x20) are sufficient for me.

Later I found, IMHO, ist is a bug in the internal getBestTextAlign member function. When I remove the two obscure angle-dependent alignment adjustments, everything works fine:

```
  getBestTextAlign: function(angle, style) {
    style = style || {textAlign: 'center', textBaseline: 'middle'};
    angle += Flotr.getTextAngleFromAlign(style);

//    if (Math.abs(Math.cos(angle)) > 10e-3) 
//      style.textAlign    = (Math.cos(angle) > 0 ? 'right' : 'left');

//    if (Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)) > 10e-3) 
//      style.textBaseline = (Math.sin(angle) > 0 ? 'top' : 'bottom');

    return style;
  },
```

I have no idea what's the idea behind this code. It is not commented at all. Sorry, no good coding practise.